# error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NewSceneSetup' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, unity3d, build-error

Версия Unity:`Unity 5.6.6f2 (64-bit)`
Не могу понять , что подключить в using чтоб ошибки не было. Добавил :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
#endif
    ...
    public class SceneManagerWindow  : MonoBehaviour
    {
    ...
        protected NewSceneSetup newSceneSetup = NewSceneSetup.DefaultGameObjects;
        protected NewSceneMode newSceneMode = NewSceneMode.Single;
    ...
    }
    ...
```

Но всё равно ошибка:

```
Assets/Scene/SceneManagerWindow.cs(15,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NewSceneSetup' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

думаю это из-за

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
#endif
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.NewScene.html) они находятся в `SceneManagement.Scene`, который в свою очередь находится в `UnityEngine.SceneManagement`, который вам и надо подключать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня это тоже подключено using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; Но всё равно ошибка

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  пробовал и так :protected UnityEditor.SceneManagement.NewSceneSetup newSceneSetup = UnityEditor.SceneManagement.NewSceneSetup.DefaultGameObjects;

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос - отметьте верный ответ.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Отметил . Только хотел отметить , когда вернулся бы опять сборке проекта . Я пока поправил в коде но другим занялся и нет времени протестировать сработало это для меня или нет . В конце недели точно буду собирать проект и если что дополню или отпишусь убрало ошибку или нет. А так спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Тогда могли не отмечать, я же не знал) Если что - пишите/оформляйте новый вопрос - поможем.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да спасибо ещё раз за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже если убрать `#if UNITY_EDITOR` - проект все равно не соберется. Заглянем в документацию к `NewSceneSetup` и `NewSceneMode` и прочтем описание:

> Used when creating a new Scene in the Editor.

Что уже намекает, что данные типы нигде, кроме как в редакторе, использовать нельзя. Если данный класс полностью отвечает за функционал, определенный для редактора - окружайте **весь** класс `#if UNITY_EDITOR`'ом:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
public class SceneManagerWindow  : MonoBehaviour
{
...
    protected NewSceneSetup newSceneSetup = NewSceneSetup.DefaultGameObjects;
    protected NewSceneMode newSceneMode = NewSceneMode.Single;
...
}
#endif
```

Либо, если данный класс лишь в некоторых местах использует API редактора - оборачивайте вызовы API во все те же `#if`:

```
public class SceneManagerWindow  : MonoBehaviour
{
...
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    protected NewSceneSetup newSceneSetup = NewSceneSetup.DefaultGameObjects;
    protected NewSceneMode newSceneMode = NewSceneMode.Single;
    #endif
...
}
```

---

### P.S.

Нет, использовать API редактора в Player билдах никак не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется вы засунули подключение библиотеки в [платформенно-зависимую компиляцию (PDC)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html), что не есть хорошо. Так как данный метод используется по другому: Например, для разделения кода под платформу IOS и Android, и тд.

А компилятор ругается из-за того что вы не настроили [Build Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/BuildSettings.html) в проекте, он как бы не видит данные строки (для него они не существуют на данный момент):

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
#endif
```

Данная ошибка, это и подтверждает (особенно последние слова):

> The type or namespace name `NewSceneSetup' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Так-как большинство IDE с плагином Unity не способны определить как вы собираетесь использовать PDC в своем проекте, они не отображают это как ошибку. По этому вы и не смогли определить в чем проблема, так как в IDE все есть и подключено, но во время сборки эти правила были исключены.

Также для более корректной работы необходимо подключить эти библиотеки так:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Comment: Нет, единственная существенная разница между Editor и Player билдами в отсутствии символа `UNITY_EDITOR`. `using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;` и вообще все редакторские сборки будут исключены из билда, а значит и использующий их код тоже сломается.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да вы правы, этот момент я пропустил.